# Nested IF function returning tiny value instead of zero

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Whilst creating a balance sheet for a lotto syndicate, I encountered this phenomenon;

[image]

Note the negative zero value in D5.  With no formatting, its actual value is `-0.0000000000000230926389122033` even though all other numbers in the sheet have no more than one or two decimal places.  The formula in D5 (as it is in all of column D) is;

```
=IF(A5="Bank",D4,IF(A5="Lotto",D4+B5,D4-B5))
```

If I replace the formula with a simple `=D4-B5` it returns a true zero, so the tiny value seems to be coming from the nested `IF`.  But why?  And can it be avoided?

Example workbook available here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33942680/Negative%20Zero%20Example.xlsx

Comment: Relevent: [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113)

Comment: Thanks David. I would understand if I were trying to perform complex arithmetic, but these are simple addition/subtraction calculations. Furthermore, if I take the IF out of the equation (pardon the pun) and just perform the resultant D4-D5 from the formula, the result is a nice round zero. What I'm failing to understand is why using IF logic would introduce this tiny fraction.

Comment: No idea ..... :/

Comment: I downloaded your file, and (in Excel 2013) a simple `=D4-B5` returns the same miniscule (but nonzero) value as the `IF` formula.